# How to adjust Prime NG P-Calendar size? Angular Project P-Calendar Size Too BIG

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

Im using Dynamic Dialog pop up and inside that component im using primeng p-calendar for date tracking. But the size of p-calendar when the calendar grid opens is very big. im unable to find a solution of how to adjust the size. Im working on an Angular project. Here is my html code. I will also attach a screenshot of how the ui looks. Thank you.

```
`<div class="section1">
            <p>Section1</p>
            <div class="calendar-container">
                <div class="calendar-item">
                    <label for="startDate">Start Date</label>
                    <p-calendar class="my-custom-calendar" [(ngModel)]="startDate" [minDate]="today" (onSelect)="onStartDateSelect()"></p-calendar>
                </div>
                <div class="calendar-item">
                    <label>End Date</label>
                    <p-calendar class="my-custom-calendar" [(ngModel)]="endDate" [minDate]="startDate"></p-calendar>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVb6B.png)

I have tried  multiple solutions found in the internet but i couldn't make it work. The calendar size is big and it is not fully viewable as you can see in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the `scale` of the `p-calendar` by doing the following:

1- Add `styleClass` property on the `p-calendar` in order to specify the calendar you want to change.
like that :

```
    <p-calendar
      inputId="basic"
      [styleClass]="'test-klass'"
      [(ngModel)]="date1"
    ></p-calendar>
```

2- In CSS file:

```
.test-klass .p-datepicker {
  scale: 0.9;
}
```